# numpy irfft by amplitude and phase spectrum

Tags: python, numpy, fft, ifft

How to compute irfft if I have only amplitude and phase spectrum of signal? In numpy docs I've found only irfft which use fourier coefficients for this transformation.

Comment: If you have amplitude and phase, then you can compute the complex spectrum as `amp*np.exp(phase*1j)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have amplitude and phase vectors for a spectrum, you can convert them to a complex (IQ or Re,Im) vector by multiplying the cosine and sine of each phase value by its associated amplitude value (for each FFT bin with a non-zero amplitude, or vector-wise).